# Смена темы приложения с помощью Preferences Framework

Tags: android

Хочу реализовать возможность пользователю выбрать стиль оформления. Перелопатил кучу ссылок. Делаю как указано тут: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings#Fragment  Ничего не получается. Помогите разобраться.

Я использую PrefereceFragment

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    changeTheme();

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 public void changeTheme() {
        sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String themePref = sharedPref.getString(SettingsFragment.CURRENT_THEME, "");
        if (themePref.equals("1")) {
            setTheme(R.style.AppThemeLight);
        } else {
            setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        }



    public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment implements
        SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    public static final String CURRENT_THEME = "CURRENT_THEME";
 @Override
   public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        if (key.equals(CURRENT_THEME)){
            Preference themePref = findPreference(key);
            themePref.setSummary(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ""));


        }


    }
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences()
                .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }



 <string-array name="entries_themes">
        <item>Light</item>
        <item>Dark</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="entry_values_themes">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
    </string-array>
```

Comment: Менять тему надо до вызова `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: @ЮрийСПб все равно не работает

Comment: Надо ещё пересоздать активити чтобы код в onCreate выполнился. Вызовите `recreate()` в момент смены темы, если вы это по нажатию на к-л кнопку делаете

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как то однажды я тоже потратил на это много времени.
Напишу решение сюда.
Для того что бы менялась тема, нужно использовать `StartActivityForResult`
Здесь покажу как использовать это на примере `PreferenceFragment`:

переход в активити настроек из основного (с вставленным фрагментом `PreferenceFragment`) я осуществляю так:

```
private int SETTINGS_ACTION = 1;`//заводим переменную в шапке`

showSettings();//нажимаем по клику, переходим в настройки.

//сам метод
private void showSettings() {
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, PreferenceActivity.class), SETTINGS_ACTION);

}
```

в `PreferenceActivity` я просто ставлю фрагмент

```
PreferenceActivity:


 if(savedInstanceState == null){
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.preference_container, new PreferenceFragment())
                .commit();
    }
```

А вот как выглядит сам фрагмент:

```
public static final int RESULT_CODE_THEME_UPDATED = 1;
public static final String THEME_CHANGE = "theme", DEFAULT_THEME = "Светлая", DARK_THEME = "Темная" ;
```

далее метод `onCreate` фрагмента:

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    findPreference(THEME_CHANGE).
            setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new RefreshActivityOnPreferenceChangeListener(RESULT_CODE_THEME_UPDATED));
```

в нем вложенный класс:

```
private class RefreshActivityOnPreferenceChangeListener implements Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener {
    private final int resultCode;

    RefreshActivityOnPreferenceChangeListener(int resultCode) {
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference p, Object newValue) {
        getActivity().setResult(resultCode);
        return true;}
}
```

ну и основное - показываем и меняем`onSharedPreferenceChanged`

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
   if (key.equals(THEME_CHANGE)) {

       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Тема изменена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       getActivity().finish();
       startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), DrawerMain.class)
               .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
   }


на всякий случай покажу xml:
<ListPreference
        android:defaultValue="@string/def_theme"
        android:dialogTitle="@string/theme_dialog_title"
        android:entries="@array/themes"
        android:entryValues="@array/themes"
        android:key="theme"
        android:summary="%s"
        android:title="@string/theme_dialog_title" />
```

где:

```
<string name="def_theme">Светлая</string>
    <string name="theme_summary">Тема приложения</string>
    <string name="theme_dialog_title">Тема приложения</string>


<string-array name="themes">
    <item>Светлая</item>
    <item>Темная</item>
</string-array>
```

И теперь в главной активности применяем результат:

```
//применение темы активити ресульт
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == SETTINGS_ACTION) {
        if (resultCode == PreferenceFragment.RESULT_CODE_THEME_UPDATED) {
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
            return;
        }
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Теперь добавляем проверку в методе `onCreate` главной активности перед super.onCreate:

```
checkStartUpTheme();

private String themeName;`//в шапке активности`
```

И собственно сам метод:

```
public void checkStartUpTheme() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    themeName = sharedPreferences.getString(MyAppInfo.THEME_CHANGE, MyAppInfo.DEFAULT_THEME);
    switch (themeName) {
        case MyAppInfo.DEFAULT_THEME:
            setTheme(R.style.Default_theme);
            break;
        case MyAppInfo.DARK_THEME:
            setTheme(R.style.Dark_Theme);
            break;

    }
}
```

Где класс MyAppInfo просто класс `Utils` в котором я храню константы, они должны совпадать по именам с `string-array name="themes"` :

public class MyAppInfo {

```
public static final String THEME_CHANGE = "theme";
public static final String DEFAULT_THEME = "Светлая";
public static final String DARK_THEME = "Темная";
```

}

На этом все, будет работать корректно.

Единственное , что бы тема применялась ко всем активностям, как то посмотрел в туториале следующую фишку:

Можно просто создать класс `BaseActivity` и унаследовать его от `AppCompatActivity`. В манифесте регестрировать не надо. А все остальные активности унаследовать от него.

```
@SuppressLint("Registered")
```

public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private String themeName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    checkStartUpTheme();//проверяем тему из настроек
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public void checkStartUpTheme() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    themeName = sharedPreferences.getString(MyAppInfo.THEME_CHANGE, MyAppInfo.DEFAULT_THEME);
    switch (themeName) {
        case MyAppInfo.DEFAULT_THEME:
            setTheme(R.style.Default_theme);
            break;
        case MyAppInfo.DARK_THEME:
            setTheme(R.style.Dark_Theme);
            break;

    }
}
```

А главную активность и все остальные делать `public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity`

Так же отдельно отмечу как работать с разметкой layout.

Что бы корректно менялись цвета итд я использую стили и там переопределяю цвета, что собственно понятно. Но ставлю знак вопроса
`style="?attr/layoutBackground"`.
Тогда в attr.xml :

```
<attr name="layoutBackground" format="reference" />
```

И в теме , например, в стветлой `<item name="layoutBackground">@style/Background_Light</item>`

```
<!-- смена картинки в фоне -->
<style name="Background_Light" parent="Default_theme">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_day</item>
</style>
```

и т д

Comment: Я так вам благодарен!  Небольшая загводка. showSettings() в MainActivity вставляем? тогда приложение будет открываться с экрана настроек.

Comment: showSetting вешаем на onClick. Так мы заходим в настройки , я просто выношу обычно отдельно, так удобнее.